# Python-Error 'bool' object is not iterable en una condicional if usando enteros

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy haciendo un programa pero no se como corregir este error, apenas empiezo a programar en python, ojala me puedan ayudar:
Me sale el error 'bool' object is not iterable en esta condición (ocupe any por que decía que mi comparación era ambigua)

```
 if(any(a!=0)):
            llegada(numejec)
            print('Lista Actual:', ListaActual)
```

tomando que 'a' es un entero que saque de una posición de un dataframe:

```
a=int(Ejecutando['ya'])
```

Algo que vi es que ese pedazo de codigo funciona despues de que actualice 'a' pero si lo quiero hacer antes me da ese error (yo lo necesito hacer antes :( )

```
        numejec=numejec+1
        print('Numero de ejecucion: ', numejec)

        Ejecutando['ya']=Ejecutando['ya']+1

        if(any(a!=0)):
            llegada(numejec)
            print('Lista Actual:', ListaActual)

        a=int(Ejecutando['ya'])
        print('ejec')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no sacaste un valor único del DataFrame, sino toda una columna (así tenga solo un registro), representada con una serie

```
Ejecutando['ya']
```

Lo puedes ver con:

```
type(Ejecutando['ya'])
```

Es de tipo serie. Si lo que querías es sacar un registro en específico, primero deberías encontrar el renglón de donde lo quieres sacar con `loc[]` mediante una condición.

Por otro lado, si tu dataframe solo tiene un renglón ¿como para qué necesitas un DataFrame? Quizás lo mejor sea usar un diccionario.

Suponiendo que aún así y por alguna razón quisieras mantener el DataFrame, y solo quieres obtener el valor del primer renglón de la columna 'ya', podrías hacerlo con:

```
Ejecutando.iloc[0]['ya']
```

Eso si te entregaría un entero (si es que guardaste un entero ahí)

Comment: Si me ayudo, muchas gracias, al hacer eso ya no necesitaba any()

Comment: Pero insisto, por la descripción de tu problema, es mejor solución un diccionario que un dataframe